# Allow gesture on UITableViewCell to fall through to underlying view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am having a problem with allowing gesture (in particular the pan gesture) on the UITableViewCell to fall through to the underlying view. I have tried set userInteractionEnabled flag of the associated UITableViewCell to false but the gesture still do not go through the UITableViewCell to the underlying view.

Below is my storyboard

[image]

How do i make the gesture in UITableViewCell to fall through to its underlying views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` delegate method. This will called whenever there is gesture recognised.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {   
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.button1]) {
        // Perform the required operation here
    }

return YES;
```

}

You can check like this:

```
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.tableView]) {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: i am not sure how i can implement this so that the gesture event falls through to the view behind the UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`. And in `UIScrollView` I found two gesture recognizers `panGestureRecognizer` and `pinchGestureRecognizer`. But I think it's bad to forbid this because this will cause your table view can't scroll any more. I suggest you to KVO that property and get touch events and handle your own things(or add new action?).

Answer (score 0):

I have added `long press event` for `UITableViewCell` like below.

May be it will help you to solve your issue.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [longPressGestureRecognizer setDelegate:(id)self];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
}
```

and then handle `action` like following.

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressGestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint point = [longPressGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath * indexPathForSelectedRow = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    if (indexPathForSelectedRow != nil && longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Then need to create `category` or `UIView` and then pass `touch` to `subview`.